# Flexslider breaking when float: left

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, flexslider

Hi there I'm trying to move flexslider to the left so I can put a block of text beside it. Currently my css is

```
.home-nav { 
  .flexslider {
    max-width: 700px;  
    margin-left: 10em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    box-shadow: -10px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    float: left;
  }     
  .welcome-text-wrapper p{
    float: right;
  }
}
```

I've tried creating and overflow, but either way I get this:

[image: error]

Any suggestions?

*EDIT Here is my haml code for this page

%h1.opening-tag Welcome

```
.home-nav
  %div.flexslider
    %ul.slides
      %li
        = image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Kali/Images/kali_slider_1.jpg")
      %li 
        = image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/Kali/Images/kali_slider_2.jpg")

  .welcome-text-wrapper
    %p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet tempor nisi. Suspendisse malesuada in leo nec pharetra. Sed non lobortis massa, vel suscipit erat. Cras cursus dui a ornare porttitor. Integer sodales dolor metus, vel consectetur nunc porta et. Pellentesque feugiat risus sed quam egestas tincidunt. In et mauris sed lacus viverra mollis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur et tincidunt est, quis ornare diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed venenatis leo sodales auctor mattis. Morbi id erat vestibulum, semper metus ac, varius ligula. Quisque orci est, lobortis sed magna quis, facilisis molestie dolor. Vestibulum leo sapien, cursus ac nisl nec, fermentum pharetra diam. Nullam urna lorem, vestibulum sed justo ac, rutrum fringilla tortor.

    %p Phasellus ornare, arcu in euismod adipiscing, tortor erat blandit felis, sed lobortis ligula magna at nulla. Sed at nunc quis nisl vehicula iaculis. Aliquam vestibulum ligula egestas purus tempus, eu tempor tortor tincidunt. Duis feugiat feugiat nisi tristique ornare. Nunc libero lorem, ultrices sit amet scelerisque sit amet, porta vitae augue. Nulla non sem vitae ante accumsan convallis eget non erat. Curabitur convallis tellus id dolor adipiscing consequat. Morbi ac purus lacinia, sodales diam eget, placerat sem. Nunc tempus accumsan dolor sodales ultricies. Nullam et imperdiet metus. Duis ac pellentesque ligula.

    %p Suspendisse egestas vel dui eget aliquet. Vivamus vitae massa ut nibh posuere tincidunt et sed dui. Pellentesque sagittis orci ut orci sodales congue. Fusce feugiat, arcu at condimentum aliquam, ipsum odio porta eros, eget dictum ligula mi id turpis. Nulla felis lectus, consectetur quis mauris ut, placerat congue neque. Vestibulum feugiat tristique euismod. Maecenas hendrerit augue eget velit vehicula, eu fringilla metus bibendum. Proin vestibulum accumsan nulla, non fermentum tortor mattis quis. Etiam et odio et felis faucibus hendrerit. Praesent euismod tincidunt magna, vitae pharetra nibh viverra ut. Etiam a ante nulla. Vestibulum quis erat sit amet felis egestas vestibulum. Fusce tristique arcu arcu, quis volutpat nisi lobortis sit amet.
```

Comment: Is there a reason  `.flexslider{` is inside `.home-nav {`? As far as I am away (I could be wrong) it shouldn't be?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.  Where is your flexslider in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes there is a reason because I'm using ruby on rails, every page the only thing that changes is the body content, so placing it .home-nav is scoping it to only change the homepage bodycontent file, as to where my flexslider is, thats the whiteline on the side. Removing float: left causes it to work but I need to place the text beside it. My code is written in haml and is just the flexslider and the text, everything else is  a seperate file